# How to generate Change Data Capture from Spanner if we restore a backup?

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

I read about CDCs in Spanner, and about Backups and Exports. My application uses CDC. If the data inserted in Spanner can go wrong such that I need to recover from a Backup that is two weeks old (say), how do I restore the backup such that my application gets the corresponding CDC updates.

Comment: Have a look at this documents on [Change stream partitions](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/change-streams/details#change_stream_partitions) & [About change streams](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/change-streams)

Comment: What about it? I had read it before, can you point to something specific in them?

Comment: When you restore a backup , it does not include the internal data of any change streams. Refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/backup/restore-backup#:~:text=It%20will%20not%20include%20the%20internal%20data%20of%20any%20change%20streams.)